# Cannot open text file containing 20 million lines

Tags: eclipse, heap-memory

I want to open a large text file (400MB) which contains 20 millions lines of domain addresses.
This is the file when I open it normally:

[image]

But when I open it in Eclipse I get this error:

[image]

I tried to change `Xms6000M` but it's not working!!

[image]

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Comment: @TreffnonX you should re-read the question

Comment: Anyway, changing the heap size where you're doing it is not the right place. That's for *your* program, but you're trying to open that file with eclipse, so it's eclipse that needs that kind of memory.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca The Domains are obviously wordbook-generated by appending two entries and adding a postfix. If that was not done just simply to generate a large dataset, then I will be seriously surprised. The question *is* specific though, I will admit that.

Comment: @TreffnonX the question is why *eclipse* doesn't open that file, not why their program doesn't work. That's what I'm pointing out, not the specifics of the question.

Comment: Use the current version of Eclipse instead of the outdated one you have. If required, increase `-Xmx` in the [`eclipse.ini`](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini) file.

Comment: thank howlger it's working!!

Answer (score 1):

Use the current version of Eclipse instead of the outdated one you have.

If required, **increase `-Xmx` in the [`eclipse.ini`](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini)** file.